# Alarm notification not working using data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I need to make a notification where in the user will choose the date and time the notification will start. In order for that, I store the date, time and notes in the Database. Now I want to start the alarm using the data from the database and using the id of each alarm as a unique id for the `PendingIntent`.

This is the how I get the data from the database

```
db=new events_database(events_main.this);
    c=db.queryData("select * from events_list ORDER BY event_ID ASC");
    if(c != null && c.moveToNext())
    {
        int id=c.getInt(0);
        String type=c.getString(1);
        String date=c.getString(2);
        String time=c.getString(3);
        String note=c.getString(4);

        String[] newDate=date.split("/");
        int year=Integer.valueOf(newDate[0]);
        int month=Integer.valueOf(newDate[1]);
        int day=Integer.valueOf(newDate[2]);

        String[] newTime=time.split(":");
        int hour=Integer.valueOf(newTime[0]);
        int min=Integer.valueOf(newTime[1]);

        Alarms(id,year,month,day,hour,min,type,note);

    }
```

After getting it I pass the data into the Alarms method

```
public void Alarms(int id, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, String type, String note) {
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        if (calendar1.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(events_main.this, events_receiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("type",type);
        intent.putExtra("note",note);
        intent.putExtra("id",   id);
        PendingIntent dog1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        final AlarmManager alarm1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm1.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), dog1);
        Toast.makeText(events_main.this, "alarms",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

then in the Receiver

```
public class events_receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int id= Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("id"));
        String note=intent.getStringExtra("note");
        String type=intent.getStringExtra("type");

        NotificationManager notificationManager2=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent dog_intent2=new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
        dog_intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent dog_pending2=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id,dog_intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder2=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(dog_pending2)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_prof_breed_icon)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +context.getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.dog))
                .setContentTitle("Pet Guide 101")
                .setContentText(type)
                .setContentText(note)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000})
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager2.notify(id,builder2.build());
    }
}
```

But for some reason the alarm doesn't get triggered. When I test the code I do get the data from the database but the alarm still doesn't get executed. If you can look it up, please tell me if I'm doing it wrong especially the part of passing the unique id into the receiver.